# How can I hide the "redirect_url" string of idp side when using CAS to do delegate authentication in CAS login page sourcecode?

Tags: saml, cas, hid, idp

I had used CAS5.1 to do delegate authenticate to other idp,(CAS as SP), it works fine.
but when user move  to the "saml2client" loging button or view source code , they can see the "redirect_url" of idp's, I just want to avoid this by simplyest way, the user cannot find the url or url be encrypted but still works, is it possiable, any help would be appreciate, thanks in advance...

Comment: Why is it a problem to know the redirect url? Someone hitting the link without having authenticated to idp will fail.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to avoid this by simplyest way, the user cannot find the url or url be encrypted but still works, is it possiable, any help would be appreciate, thanks in advance...

You misunderstand how the web works. Any URL that passes through the client browser will by definition be visible to the client and cannot be "hidden" or encrypted. If you want to "hide" the URL to add some sort of security measure, you're going about this the wrong way.